# How to check diference between two times in two MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

So I've got two tables:

ic:

```
id | created
---|--------------------
1  | 2016-03-31 16:20:03
2  | 2016-03-31 16:25:18
3  | 2016-03-31 16:28:09
```

status:

```
id | ic_id | timestamp
---|--------------------
1  | 1     | 2016-03-31 16:20:03
2  | 5     | 2016-03-31 16:25:18
3  | 5     | 2016-03-31 16:28:09
```

I now want to find the average difference between the `ic.created` and the `status.timestamp` of the first corresponding record in the `status` table. I started out with this:

```
SELECT status.`timestamp` - informed_consent.created as difference
FROM status
WHERE status.`timestamp` > '2017-06-19' 
AND status.ic_id IN (
    SELECT informed_consent.id
    FROM informed_consent
    WHERE informed_consent.id = status.ic_id; 
);
```

But I immediately get an `error in my mysql syntax`. I guess I can also use a left join, but I'm kinda lost here.

Could anybody help me out in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand where you are exactly having a problem. Is it in the `LEFT JOIN` or in getting `Average` ?

Comment: In what term you want to get the `average difference` i mean in `day` or `month` or `year` or anything else because there are both the dates are equal so it my return `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `inner join` instead of `sub query` due to `informed_consent.created` is not present in outer sql,it's in the sub query

```
SELECT status.`timestamp`,status.`timestamp` - informed_consent.created as difference
FROM status
JOIN informed_consent ON informed_consent.id = status.ic_id
WHERE status.`timestamp` > '2017-06-19'
```

Comment: Thanks for the query, but does that use the first corresponding record in the status table?

Comment: @kramer65 it will find all the result that match the `where` clause,if you want to get the average,you need to use `AVG()`,just updated my answer

Comment: What I mean is that this gets all corresponding records from the `status` table. I only want the first corresponding result from the `status` table though. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: @kramer65 what do you mean by first result? if you want use first result,you need to use `order by` and `limit`

Comment: true. So I want the first record of the `status` table ordered by status.timestamp. I guess that still needs a subquery, but I'm unsure how.

Comment: @kramer65 order by day or by month? you need to specify it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173397/discussion-between-lucumt-and-kramer65).